# Allocating C structures to off chip memory?

Tags: c

I'd like to know how to allocate C structures to off chip memory.  What I am trying to say is that I do not want the compiler to allocate space on the stack or data region of my internal memory for these structures.  I'd like to some how have the compiler realize that the actual data for these structures will be stored externally and therefore it should not make space in internal memory for them.  How would I go about doing that?

Here is my first crack at it, I think what I have done is correct and will generate the desired result, but I just want to be sure.

```
msgFIFO *cmdFIFOPtr;    
msgFIFO *respFIFOPtr;   

volatile struct eleDataStrut *eleDataStrtPtr; 
volatile struct eleStatStrut *eleStatStrtPtr; 
volatile struct SysStatStrut *SysStatStrutPtr; 
volatile struct CommsCmdStrut *CommsCmdStrutPtr;

volatile struct navDataStrut *navDataStrtPtr;
volatile struct navStatStrut *navStatStrtPtr;
volatile struct OrienDataStrut *orienDataStrtPtr;
volatile struct navGPSDataStrut *navGPSDataStrutPtr;

volatile unsigned char *ele_vcs_array;
volatile unsigned char *nav_vcs_array;

void init_icsb_pointers( void ) {

    //volatile char *SharedRam1_ = (volatile char *) 0x10000000;

    cmdFIFOPtr     = (struct msgFIFO *) 0x10000000;
    respFIFOPtr    = (struct msgFIFO *) ( (int) cmdFIFOPtr + sizeof(struct msgFIFO) );

    eleDataStrtPtr  = (volatile struct eleDataStrut *) ( (int) respFIFOPtr + sizeof(struct msgFIFO) );
    eleStatStrtPtr  = (volatile struct eleStatStrut *) ( (int) eleDataStrtPtr + sizeof(struct eleDataStrut) );
    SysStatStrutPtr = (volatile struct SysStatStrut *) ( (int) eleStatStrtPtr + sizeof(struct eleStatStrut) );

    navDataStrtPtr = (volatile struct navDataStrut *) ( (int) SysStatStrutPtr + sizeof(struct SysStatStrut) );
    navStatStrtPtr = (volatile struct navStatStrut *) ( (int) navDataStrtPtr + sizeof(struct navDataStrut) );
    orienDataStrtPtr = (volatile struct OrienDataStrut *) ( (int) navStatStrtPtr + sizeof(struct navStatStrut) );
    navGPSDataStrutPtr = (volatile struct navGPSDataStrut *) ( (int) orienDataStrtPtr + sizeof(struct OrienDataStrut));
    CommsCmdStrutPtr   = (volatile struct CommsCmdStrut *) ( (int) navGPSDataStrutPtr + sizeof(struct navGPSDataStrut));

    ele_vcs_array = (volatile unsigned char *) eleStatStrtPtr;
    nav_vcs_array = (volatile unsigned char *) navDataStrtPtr;
}
```

Comment: This is a job for the linker. Look into linker scripts, particularly those used for MCUs.

Comment: You're never going to get an answer until you tell us what compiler and platform.

Comment: You should at least run this code and try it out. Until you can tell us how it behaves, the only thing we can do is give you a general code review, and there's a [site dedicated to that](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). (Note that they require working code - so you should confirm its behavior before opening a review request there too)

Comment: The code works fine, a review of the functionality of the code is not what I am asking for.

Comment: MIPS gcc compiler, the processor platform is custom.  Anything specific that you need to know?

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods to allocate variables at specific locations:

- Via Linker
- Via Pointer

Look at your Linker's command file.  For some linkers, you'll need to declare a segment for the variables, then use special syntax to put that variable in the block.

An example of the syntax could be:  `MyClass my_variable @ "segment_name";`

You could also set a pointer to the address in memory:

```
struct USB_Registers;
USB_Registers * p_usb_1 = (USB_Registers *) 0x12345678;
p_usb_1->transmit_register = 'A';
```

Another possible method is to assign pointers to each member using pointers:

```
#define USB_1_BASE_ADDRESS (0x12345678)
uint32_t * p_usb1_transmit_register = (uint32_t)(USB_1_BASE_ADDRESS + TRANSMIT_REG_OFFSET);
*p_usb1_transmit_register = 'B';
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you *may* run into (depending on the type of processor you're using) is alignment.

For example, assume `eleDataStrut` starts with a 32-bit value, and has a total size of 13 bytes. If `eleDataStrtPtr` is at address `0x10000040`, then your code will put `eleStatStrtPtr` at address `0x1000004D`. That's a big problem if the processor needs 32-bit values to be aligned on 4 byte boundaries.

The solution is to make one large structure that contains all of the other structures, so that the compiler will take care of any alignment issues. Like this:

```
struct Everything
{
    msgFIFO a;
    msgFIFO b;

    struct eleDataStrut  c;
    struct eleStatStrut  d;
    struct SysStatStrut  e;
    struct CommsCmdStrut f;

    // and all the rest of them
};

msgFIFO *cmdFIFOPtr;
msgFIFO *respFIFOPtr;

volatile struct eleDataStrut *eleDataStrtPtr;
volatile struct eleStatStrut *eleStatStrtPtr;
volatile struct SysStatStrut *SysStatStrutPtr;
volatile struct CommsCmdStrut *CommsCmdStrutPtr;

void init_icsb_pointers( void )
{
    struct Everything *everything = (void *)0x10000000;

    cmdFIFOPtr  = &everything.a;
    respFIFOPtr = &everything.b;

    eleDataStrtPtr   = (volatile struct eleDataStrut *)  &everything.c;
    eleStatStrtPtr   = (volatile struct eleStatStrut *)  &everything.d;
    SysStatStrutPtr  = (volatile struct SysStatStrut *)  &everything.e;
    CommsCmdStrutPtr = (volatile struct CommsCmdStrut *) &everything.f;

    // and all the rest
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! This is indeed a problem that I have ran into several times, and the way I was solving it was manually ensuring that the structs all started and ended on a word boundary by placing dummy elements of the size and type where I needed them.  I will review this method and see if it is indeed a solution.

Comment: @asic_designer You're welcome. Let me know how it goes :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with special memory, you must be using some cross-compiler & linker.

Declaring pointers and initializing them by hand is a highway to hell.

You will basically sweat dozens of lines of code that will soon be a pain to maintain once you will have mapped half a dozen areas.

This amounts to doing inefficiently what the linker/locater can easily achieve with a couple of directives.
This would also allow the compiler to treat these pointers as constants, generating the most efficient code.

Unfortunately these directives are compiler/linker specific, though.

I would advise to use hand-crafted pointers only if you only need to map 2-3 small areas at most and access time is not critical.

Comment: Yes indeed:)   If the memory-map is in non-trivial  blocks of RAM/ROM then instructing the linker to appropriately map the data segments/sections is the easiest/safest way.